# need to match data of one table with another

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to match data of one table with another. As Table one as only one row and table second has many row as per the calendar.

Table details:-

First table:-

```
A           B            C          D         E               G     

600       MT_000        6765    29-04-23    30-04-23    WEEK
          MT            6758    01-05-23    31-05-23    MONTH
601       MT_0001       6771    01-06-23    30-06-23    WEEK
```

Second table:-

```
A       B            C         D                    
601     MT          6758    07-05-23            
601     MT          6758    14-05-23                   
601     MT          6758    21-05-23                   
601     MT          6758    28-05-23               
601     MT          6758    28-05-23                
601     MT          6758    04-06-23
```

Want data like this :-

```
A    B        C       D          E 
601  MT    6758    07-05-23   MONTH 
601  MT    6758    14-05-23   MONTH 
601  MT    6758    21-05-23   MONTH
601  MT    6758    28-05-23   MONTH
601  MT    6758    28-05-23   MONTH
601  MT    6758    04-06-23   WEEK
```

Dependency on Column A should be there value can null also.

I tried join both the table but data is not correct. Giving 18 row as each row is comparing with each other.

Please help me with this issue.
For more clearity you may ask q.

Comment: Can you add the related table structure with some data?

Comment: There is table between table 1 and table 2 so intermediate table spilts month dates into week dates but now it need to match 'MONTH' in table one as you can see there is 01-05-23 till 31-05-23 is MONTH, So i need this MONTH is second table where dates are between 01-05-23 to 31-05-23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` the two tables on the date range (and, maybe, the start of the `b` columns):

```sql
SELECT t2.*, t1.g
FROM   table2 t2
       INNER JOIN table1 t1
       ON (t1.b LIKE t2.b || '%' AND t2.d BETWEEN t1.d AND t1.e)
ORDER BY t2.b, t2.d
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (A, B, C, D, E, G) AS
SELECT 600,  'MT_000',  6765, DATE '2023-04-29', DATE '2023-04-30', 'WEEK'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'MT',      6758, DATE '2023-05-01', DATE '2023-05-31', 'MONTH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 601,  'MT_0001', 6771, DATE '2023-06-01', DATE '2023-06-30', 'WEEK'  FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (A, B, C, D) AS
SELECT 601, 'MT', 6758, DATE '2023-05-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 601, 'MT', 6758, DATE '2023-05-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 601, 'MT', 6758, DATE '2023-05-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 601, 'MT', 6758, DATE '2023-05-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 601, 'MT', 6758, DATE '2023-05-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 601, 'MT', 6758, DATE '2023-06-04' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| A | B | C | D | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 601 | MT | 6758 | 2023-05-07 00:00:00 | MONTH |
| 601 | MT | 6758 | 2023-05-14 00:00:00 | MONTH |
| 601 | MT | 6758 | 2023-05-21 00:00:00 | MONTH |
| 601 | MT | 6758 | 2023-05-28 00:00:00 | MONTH |
| 601 | MT | 6758 | 2023-05-28 00:00:00 | MONTH |
| 601 | MT | 6758 | 2023-06-04 00:00:00 | WEEK |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bmg2SPz0)

Answer (score 1):

Its appear that you are looking for whether the rows in *table2* are `WEEK` or `MONTH`. If that's what you want, use a `inner join` as shown below:

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.G
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t2.D between t1.D and t1.E
order by t2.A, t1.D
```

Result :

```
A   B   C       D           G
601 MT  6758    07-MAY-23   MONTH
601 MT  6758    14-MAY-23   MONTH
601 MT  6758    21-MAY-23   MONTH
601 MT  6758    28-MAY-23   MONTH
601 MT  6758    28-MAY-23   MONTH
601 MT  6758    04-JUN-23   WEEK
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6srUGhMR)